# Error: "Unexpected end of file" in .bash_profile

Tags: bash, shell

When I execute `source ~/.bash_profile` I get this error:

```
line 14 syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I tried to delete the last line to no avail.

```
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
. ~/.bashrc
fi

if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
source ~/.git-completion.bash
fi

PS1='\[\e[0;36m\]\W\[\e[m\]\[\e[1;31m\]\$\[\e[m\]'
if [ "$PS1" ]; then PS1="[\e[0;36m]\W\n[\e[m][\e[1;31m]\$[\e[m]" fi
function gi() { curl -L -s https://www.gitignore.io/api/$@ ;}
export LSCOLORS=cxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
```

Comment: Why to test PS1 if you have just set it ? It's always true. `source` and `.` command are same.

Comment: `[ "$PS1" ] && echo "PS1 value is $PS1" `

Answer (score 5):

There's a missing semicolon:

```
if [ "$PS1" ]; then PS1="[\e[0;36m]\W\n[\e[m][\e[1;31m]\$[\e[m]" fi
```

should be

```
if [ "$PS1" ]; then PS1="[\e[0;36m]\W\n[\e[m][\e[1;31m]\$[\e[m]"; fi
```

Or, format it the same way as your other `if` statements above this one.

Comment: I did that and removed the last list as well. but now I am not getting the prompt when starting the terminal. Just the first line (Last login: somedate ttys002)

Comment: A couple of things. For me, The only thing in my .bash_profile is ". ~/.bashrc". .bashrc contains PS1 setting, and everything else. I don't test for PS1, I just set it. Also, you need to put backslashes before each bracket surrounding your escape codes in PS1. For your prompt to work the way you want, it should be PS1='\\[\e[36m\\]\W\n\\[\e[1;31m\\]\$\\[\e[0m\\]'. Hope that helps - matt